# Visual Studio Code Can't debug Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

Recently ,My Visual Studios Code can't run in "Start Debugging" ,but it can run in "Run Without Debugging" .

The error message show it can't find the _thread module .
The _thread module is in Python3 , I think the debugging mode using the Python3 configuration ,but I can't find where I can setting the debugging configuration

How should I do any setting to make my debugging can work ?

Below is my error message:

```
(venv) linlowa@linlowa-MacBook-Pro lab01 %  cd /Users/linlowa/Documents/company/python_lab/lab01 ; /usr/bin/env /Users/li
nzeyu/Documents/company/python_lab/lab01/venv/bin/python /Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFi
les/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 55883 -- /Users/linlowa/Documents/company/python_lab/lab01/lab01.py linlowa 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from debugpy.server import cli
  File "/Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
  File "/Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/_vendored/force_pydevd.py", line 37, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py", line 362, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle._pydev_saved_modules import thread, threading
  File "/Users/linlowa/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 94, in <module>
    import _thread as thread;    verify_shadowed.check(thread, ['start_new_thread', 'start_new', 'allocate_lock'])
ImportError: No module named _thread
```

Comment: You need to select a python version on vscode. It looks like is taking the default Python version of your local machine. So you need to install a virutalenv that contains a different python version and that doesn't cause any conflicts with your Pythons local installation

Comment: Yes ,I had installed the virtualenv package ,but vscode still can not run in debugging.

Comment: please share your `launch.json` and `settings.json` file

Comment: `launch.json`{    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: 目前檔案",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
            ,"args": ["linlowa"]
        }
    ]
}


`setting.json`
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
}

Comment: @linlowa Have you had any problems with debugging before? After reading the contents of your two files, I feel that it is not the problem of the configuration file

Comment: @MingJie This problem has appeared in the past two weeks .

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

---

Click <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and search for `Python: select interpreter`. Then select the correct one

[image: Vscode command bar]

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

---

Set global default interpreter to `python3` or `python3.x` in settings:

[image: Default python interpreter setting]

---

Making a new folder/workspace, and debug a test script. Make sure this new folder is not a virtual environment, to test if `venv` is the issue.

Comment: I tried it ,but still get the error

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your launch/debug config?

Comment: Yes ,I had remove my launch.json file ,but it still appear this error .

Comment: I'll add a few more things to try